# PHP mailer not sending, while smtp says mail is sent

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Here is my code

```
$subject  = 'Verification code';
   $message  = '
      <html>
       <head>
         <title>Here is your Verification Code</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         <p>Please use this verification code this is a one time verification '. $fourRandomDigit.'</p>
       </body>
      </html>
      ';
     //Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.test.io';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = 421;
        $mail->Username = 'name';
        $mail->Password = 'pass';                            
        
       //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('from@sof.com', 'name');
        $mail->addAddress('to@sof.com');        //Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('from@sof.com', 'name');
        
    //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);         //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject =  $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        
       if (!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "Error while sending Email.";
       } else {
          echo "Email sent successfully";
       }
```

My smtp server shows that the mail is sent but the mails are not being received, also the "Email sent successfully" is being printed,so i am a bit confused where am i wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sending an email is the easy part, getting it to be accepted by the receiving mail server is an art form. See: [SPF, DKIM, DMARC: The 3 Pillars of Email Authentication](https://www.higherlogic.com/blog/spf-dkim-dmarc-email-authentication/). (link is just meant as an introduction to this topic)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail has lots of hints as to what possible reasons might be.

Comment: Make sure to set a valid email for return path and to check the spam folder (Gmail routinely classifies as spam all the failed delivery reports I get).

Answer (score 0):

Your e-mail is probably considred as **SPAM**.

To help you resolve each little detail that could cause the issue, I recommend using [mail-tester.com](https://www.mail-tester.com/) (or any other equivalent tool)

Comment: It said my email is almost perfect, i guess i am doing something wrong in the code.

Comment: @MukashWasti If you got a result from mail-tester it means they actually received your e-mail

Comment: at fist i composed a mail and send it, then i got the result, but now i tried sending it via my code, and i got no response from them.

Comment: @MukashWasti Yes, you need to send them the e-mail the way you want to test it, of course. If they didn't receive your e-mail sent by PHPMailer, then the problem comes from your server. Do you have the **sendmail** extension installed? Could you try sending an e-mail throught the PHP `mail()` function?

Comment: using mail() works fine, but it sends the mail to spam, can you guide me how to set up smtp in mail()?

Comment: If you're using mail(), you are, by definition, not using SMTP. The PHP mail function calls a sendmail binary through a shell, it doesn't use SMTP from PHP's perspective.

Comment: @MukashWasti As @Synchro said the `mail()` function can't use SMTP. Your problem seems to come from your server configuration or SMTP address. Are you sure **smtp.test.io** is allowed to send e-mails from **sof.com** throught the **421 port** ?

Comment: They are not the real credentials, i changed them while posting the question, as i mentioned in the question my SMTP dashboard shows that the mail is sent but mails are not showing in the gmail etc

Comment: @MukashWasti Understood. Yet if mail-test.com doesn't receive your e-mail I really doubt it was properly sent. Maybe contact your hoster for more info than given by your dashboard.